# What programs do i need to change my application language? c# .net 4.5.1 devexpress

Tags: c#, winforms, windows-8.1, .net-4.5, devexpress-windows-ui

EDIT: Sorry, i forgot to say that im using devexpress also...
i just figured out that it has a folder resource called ES, i had to copy this folder + the basic dlls, now it works...... even when i searched a solution using devexpress keyword, they say the same thing about CurrentUICulture, thats why i get confuse and couldn't find a solution :/

I know the code to change the language, something like this works for me....

```
System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("es-PE");
System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("es-ES");
```

IT WORKS CORRECTLY, but only in my development computer where all the programs needed are installed by default. When i try the application in the client computer, it doesn't change the language...

i have installed those programs already, is anything else i need???...

Microsoft .NET Framework 4 Multi-Targeting Pack (83.4 MB)
Microsoft .NET Framework 4.5.1 (38.8 MB)
Microsoft .NET Framework 4.5.1 (español) (2.93 MB)

PD: i googled a lot, but for some reason, it only shows me code solutions, so im here

Comment: Does the client computer have the spanish language installed?

Comment: Yes, the normal netframework, and the language pack one.... also the S.O i'ts in spanish by default

Comment: Do you have the satellite assemblies created for each language you want to support for your application? Do note that you have to provide the translations of the onscreen messages, etc. yourself. .NET won't do that automatically.

Comment: Im not an advanced programmer, and i dont want a complex translation, i just want the simple one that comes by default in netframework..... "i think" my code isn't the problem, since the translation works correctly in my development computer, but when i try the same application in the client computer, it's in english (for ex. when i right clic, a control, it shows me english option in that computer)